# Google map js api hai issues not work due to browser resolution

Tags: javascript, google-maps, browser, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

i'm using google map js api. it will work fine when browser resolution is bye default 100%. if i increase the resolution and reload page it not works. it just work for maximum 100% and less than 100%.

I try this code but not works for me.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function () {
            map.setCenter(center);
        });
```

issue is addDomListener is  not define.

Comment: Are you doing google.maps.event.addDomListener after Google map has initialised

Comment: yes i'm doing but it not works

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDomListener' of undefined

Comment: What jaromanda is saying is that the error means you are doing the code above in a way that doesn't know about the google maps javascript. That could be something simple like, you forgot to include the correct script or have it declared after your code is running, or it could be something complex like you have a firewall that is preventing google maps services from coming across the network. Either way, you will need to include more code to get a more definitive answer.